# Это корректный метод сортировки?

Tags: массивы, java

Это корректный метод сортировки для ArrayList?
Проблема в том что список не сортируется

```
out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
    n = (out.countTokens());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String[] words = { out.nextToken().toString() };
        final List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
        Collections.sort(wordList);
        System.out.println(wordList.toString());
    }
```

Comment: >Проблема в том что список не сортируется

вы, наверное, удивитесь, но раз список не сортируется, то это некорректный метод

Comment: @DreamChild, кто бы мог подумать. Поразительно!

Comment: @Flammable если вы вдруг не заметили, мои слова были сарказмом, а не словами в стиле Капитана Очевидность

Comment: > мои слова были сарказмом

Если вы вдруг не заметили, мои тоже. Так-то! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, конечно.

Вы в цикле берёте следующий токен, составляете список из одного элемента, и сортируете этот список. Понятно, что сортировка одноэлементного списка ничего не делает.

Попробуйте так (проверка: http://ideone.com/hijecS):

```
String[] words = input.toString().split("\\s+");
final List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
Collections.sort(wordList);
```

Или даже так (проверка: http://ideone.com/GHpXyZ):

```
String[] words = input.toString().split("\\s+");
Arrays.sort(words);
```